# Get the variable data/result from the promise in React JS after running it through map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I want the result of activeCustomers array inside the last then but I keep getting an error saying arrow function expects a return. Not sure how I can get activeCustomers?

```
const CreateCustomer = (storeData) => {
  let activeOrganization = null;
  storeData.Org
    .getOrganization()
    .then(function createCustomer(organization) {
      activeOrganization = organization[0];

      const dataArray= storeData.attributes;
      activeOrganization 
        .createAttributes(
          attributeType[0],
          getSomeData(dimensions)
        )
        .then(function Properties(createdAttribute) {
          updateCustomerProperty(createdAttribute, attributeType[0]);
        });
       activeOrganization 
        .createAttributes(
          attributeType[1],
          getSomeData(dimensions)
        )
        .then(function Properties(createdAttribute) {
          updateCustomerProperty(createdAttribute, attributeType[1]);
        });
     }).then(() => {
      activeOrganization
        .getCustomers()
        .then((cusomters) => {
          const activeCustomers = [];
          cusomters.map((customer) => {
            activeCustomers.push(customer);
          });
          return activeCustomers;
        })
        .then((activeCustomers) => {
          console.log(activeCustomers);
        });
    });
};

//Now I want the result of activeCustomers array inside the last then but I keep getting an error saying arrow function expects a return. Not sure how I can get activeCustomers?
```

I want the result of activeCustomers array inside the last then but I keep getting an error saying arrow function expects a return. Not sure how I can get activeCustomers?

Comment: cause it should have a return value otherwise you can use a regular function`.then(function(activeCustomers) {
          console.log(activeCustomers);
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example i think you received a warning. But still how to access to activeCustomers it depends on how you want to use it there are you storing it.

If you want to store it globally then you can store it like that

```
let activeCustomers;
....
.then((cusomters) => {
          activeCustomers = [];
          cusomters.map((customer) => {
            activeCustomers.push(customer);
          });
          return activeCustomers;
        })
```

But i think it's better to rewrite to async/await.

```
const CreateCustomer = async (storeData) => {
  let activeOrganization = null;
  const [activeOrganization] = await storeData.Org
    .getOrganization();

  const activeOrgPrs = attributeType.map(x => activeOrganization 
        .createAttributes(
          x,
          getSomeData(dimensions)
        )));

  const attrs = await Promise.all(activeOrgPrs);

  attrs.forEach((attr, i) => {
      updateCustomerProperty(attr, attributeType[i]);
   })
  
   const cusomters = await activeOrganization
        .getCustomers();
   return cusomters;
};
```

And you can use it like `const customers = await CreateCustomer(someData);`
or like `CreateCustomer(someData).then((cusomters) => { activeCustomers = cusomters; return null;(if it keeps to return errors)});`

Comment: what is the difference in the Just noticed section? What should I do to fix my code? I cannot see any difference

Comment: I found out that i was wrong on JUST NOTICED section so i removed it. Do you use es-lint? And What kind of error you have? es-lint or build error?

Comment: I like the async and await but can you change the code to use map instead of running two awaits to create attributes and show me how will that work and what would we wait as we have to update the properties for each map

Comment: I didn't catch your question because i don't know about scope that you have around your method) Do you want to updateCustomerProperty based on attribute in circle or in 'parallel' way?

Comment: If you see in my question. I am calling createAttributes multiple times but I want to call that in a map function. I was asking if you can write using map operator

Comment: You can't call async/await in map function. Also it's bad idea to fetch/calculate something in map function. You can use circle or Promise.all())

Comment: Updated sample with Promise.all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219672/discussion-between-learn-aspnet-and-boikov).